# Cloned GPT drive with Clonezilla to larger drive and can't increase partition size

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, clone, gpt, clonezilla

Cloned GPT drive with Clonezilla to larger drive and can't increase partition size.

Before this, I tried to use AOMEI Backupper Standard and experienced the same issue.

Tried EaseUS Partition Manager, Windows' Disk Management and GParted on Linux.

The filesystem of the partitions are: ext4 and NTFS.

Also tried on a Live USB.

[image: GParted]

Comment: What software are you using to increase the partition size?

Comment: @CliffArmstrong Tried EaseUS Partition Manager, Windows' Disk Management and GParted on Linux

Comment: Thanks. It would help to add any new info like that to your question so others trying to help see it immediately. Next question is what is the filesystem used on the partition you are trying to enlarge?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of GParted or Windows Disk Management (GParted is preferred)

Comment: @gronostaj Done

Comment: The problem would seem to be the Linux swap partition at the end of the existing filesystem. I would (using a bootable Linux disk) remove said partition - swap is temporary space - then expand the other partitions and recreate swap at the end of the disk. You will probably need to update /etc/fstab on your Linux partition

Comment: @davidgo So it seems the problem is with not being able to resize non-adjacent partitions, as I can only resize /dev/sda7 deleting the swap partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true that I can't resize sda5 because there is no adjacent free space that I could assign to it, I found a way to do it without *manually* move partition and that is:

On AOMEI Partition Assistant, Create a Partition then right click new partition->Allocate Free Space, select to To drive you want to allocate into.

Since it doesn't allow to allocate all space, I just deleted the partition after allocating free space, after all this hit Apply and it will ask you to reboot to continue the process.

Moving the partitions takes a while so sit back a wait.

Answer (score 2):

You can't resize `sda5` because there is no adjacent free space that you could assign to it. You have to move `sda6`, `sda7` and `sda8` out of the way.

`sda6` looks like a Windows recovery partition. From my experience moving these can result in inability to boot into recovery. In such case you'd have to use a Windows flash drive for any recovery. You can try to fix it with the `reagentc` command in Windows Command Line later, but I won't guide you through this. Just run it before dealing with partitions and take a screenshot or make notes before you proceed. You'll want to recreate those settings later if recovery breaks.

Both `sda6` and `sda7` can be moved with GParted. If I remember correctly, older versions of GParted don't allow moving swap partitions such as `sda8`. However the version provided with Ubuntu 19.04 can do that, so you can boot it from USB if your version turns out problematic.

Data partitions (`sda5`, `sda6`, `sda7`) will have to be unmounted to work on them. The swap partition (`sda8`) must be currently unused. This can be achieved by booting from USB or by using the command `sudo swapoff -a` to disable swap until reboot.

Start moving partitions with `sda8`, then proceed to `sda7` and `sda6`. Finally resize `sda5` to desired size. GParted will let you batch operations, but in my experience it sometimes causes unhelpful error messages or leaves small gaps of unused space between partitions, so I'd recommend moving them one by one, applying changes after each operation.